# Get cookie from remote domain by HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

I have to pages on different domains: http://domain1/page1.aspx and http://domain2/page2.aspx (in real it's http handler).
By WebHttpRequest I'm sending post request from page1 to page2.

```
string result;
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://domain2/page2.aspx");
webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.ContentLength = 0;
using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
{
  if (webResponse == null)
    return null;
   var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true);    
   try
   {
     result = reader.ReadToEnd();
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
       return null;
     }
   finally
   {
     reader.Close();
   }
 }
 return result.Deserialize();
```

I know, that there is a cookie on domain2, but when I'm getting in page2.aspx cookies collection is empty.
When I'm making simple Response.Redirect to page2, cookie exists.
So is it possible to make such requests and where I did mistake? Or maybe there is another method to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the request to page 2 via code and not via browser. Typically its a browser that sends cookie (associated with site) to web servers. In your case, you need to transfer cookie name-values manually in code from page1's response to page2's request (assuming thats what you want/mean).

Further, cookies are disabled by default in `HttpWebRequest`, so even if page2 server code is adding some cookie, it won't be seen in response object unless you enable them using [CookiContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) property (read the documentation/example in the link).